# Adding watermark to image using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been trying to add watermark to image via codeigniter, below is my code, the images, resize and thumb are all working, but watermark seems not to work. I have actually read through similar post on this forum, but non seems to work for me, maybe there is something am not doing right

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model("user_model");

        /*if($this->user_model->login_status() === FALSE)
        {
            redirect('main');
        }*/

        $this->load->helper("file");

        $this->load->library("greetings");
        $this->load->helper("error_message");
        $this->load->helper("custom_date_helper");

        //$this->greetings->show_greetings();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if($this->user_model->login_status() === FALSE)
        {
            $msg="You need to login before you can submit entry!";
            echo $msg;
        }
        else
        {
            $contest_id=strip_tags($_GET["contest_id"]);
            $data["contest_id"]=$contest_id;
            $str = $this->load->view('upload/upload_form',$data);
            echo trim($str);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Uploads a new contest entry
     */
    public function do_upload()
    {
        $contest_id=$this->input->post("contest_id");

        $config["file_name"]=$this->session->userdata("username").'_'.time();
        $config["upload_path"]= $this->config->item("custom_upload_path");
        $config["allowed_types"]="jpeg|jpg|gif|png";
        $config["max_size"]="8888";







        $this->load->library("upload",$config);

        $field_name="file";

        $title=$this->input->post("title");
        $description=$this->input->post("description");

        $this->load->library("form_validation");

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("terms","Terms","callback_accept_terms");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("title","Title","required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("description","Description","required");

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<div class='error'>","</div>");

        $date=new DateTime();
        $date_uploaded=$date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload($field_name) OR $this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {  
            if(empty($_POST["submit"]))
            {
                $data["error"]='';
                $data["contest_id"]=$this->input->post("contest_id");
                $this->load->view("upload/upload_form",$data);
            }

            else
            {
                $data["error"]=$this->upload->display_errors();
                $data["contest_id"]=$this->input->post("contest_id");
                $this->load->view("upload/upload_form_1",$data);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            $this->load->model("contest_model");

           $file_info=$this->upload->data();











            $username=$this->session->userdata("username");

            $uploaded_by=$this->contest_model->get_user($username); 

            $path=$file_info["file_name"];  



                   $this->watermark($path);         


            $this->_create_thumb($path); 
            $this->resize($path); 



            $info=array(
                'contest_id'=>$contest_id,
                'uploaded_by'=>$uploaded_by,
                'path'=>$path,
                'title'=>$title,
                'description'=>$description,
                'date_uploaded'=>$date_uploaded,
                'status'=>0,
            );

            if($this->contest_model->already_submitted($contest_id,$uploaded_by) === FALSE)
            {
                if($this->contest_model->add_submission($info) === TRUE)
                {
                    $msg="Your submission was recorded and awaiting for admin approval!";
                }

                else
                {
                    $msg="There was something wrong! Try later!";
                }
            }

            else
            {
                $msg="You have already submitted your entry for this contest! <span style='color:red;'> You can enter one photo per contest.</span>";
            }

            $this->session->set_flashdata( 'message', array( 'title' => '', 'content' => $msg, 'type' => 'message' ));
            redirect("user/profile/");
        }
    }

    public function accept_terms($terms)
    {
        if($terms == "on")
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message("accept_terms","You must agree with this");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function validate_breed($breed_type)
    {
        if($breed_type == "none")
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message("validate_breed","You must select a breed");
            return FALSE;
        }

        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }


    private function _create_thumb($image_name)
    {
        $this->load->library("image_lib");
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = 'uploads/'.$image_name;




        $config['new_image'] = 'uploads/'.$image_name;


        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = 135;
        $config['height'] = 135;

        $this->image_lib->clear();
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        $this->image_lib->resize();
    }




    function change_file_name($image)
    {
        $img_arr=pathinfo($image);
        $filename=$img_arr["filename"];
        $extension=$img_arr["extension"];
        $thumb=$filename."-new.".$extension;
        return $thumb;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
        $this->load->helper("directory");
        $map=directory_map("uploads");

        $i=0;

        foreach($map as $file)
        {
            if(!strstr($file,"thumb") AND !strstr($file,"new"))
            {
                if(!in_array($this->change_file_name($file), $map))
                {
                    $i++;
                    echo $file;
                    $this->resize($file);
                    echo "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }

        echo $i;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo count($map);
        //array_map(array($this, "_create_thumb"), $map);
    }

    private function resize($file)
    {
        $this->load->library("image_lib");
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = 'uploads/'.$file;
        $config['new_image'] = 'uploads/'.$this->change_file_name("$file");
        $config['create_thumb'] = false;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = true;
        $config['dynamic_output'] = false;
        $config['quality'] = '100%';
        $config['width'] = 300;
        $config['height'] = 1000;

        $this->image_lib->clear();
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
    }
//watermark function
function watermark($image_name)
    {
        $this->load->library("image_lib");
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = 'uploads/'.$image_name;

$config['wm_text'] = 'Copyright 2006 - John Doe';
$config['wm_type'] = 'text';
$config['wm_font_path'] = './system/fonts/texb.ttf';
$config['wm_font_size'] = '16';
$config['wm_font_color'] = 'ffffff';
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
$config['wm_padding'] = '20';


 $this->image_lib->clear();
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
//$this->image_lib->clear();

if ( $this->image_lib->watermark())
{
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
//var_dump(gd_info());

}


}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  // Define it in configuration file. And call it
    // About configurations: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html
    $wm_font_size = 16; // Watermark height (font size) contains 16% of image 

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config['image_library'] = 'GD2';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
            $_FILES['file']['name'] = $files['file']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['type'] = $files['file']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['error'] = $files['file']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['size'] = $files['file']['size'][$i];
            $config['source_image'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $config['wm_text'] = 'Copyright example.com';
            $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
            $config['wm_font_size'] = ceil($files['file'][image_height][$i]/100*wm_font_size);
            $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
            $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->watermark();

            $config['source_image'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $config['wm_overlay_path'] = './application/assets/images/example.png';
            $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
            $config['width'] = '50';
            $config['height'] = '50';
            $config['padding'] = '50';
            $config['wm_opacity'] = '100';
            $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
            $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
            $config['wm_vrt_offset'] = '100';
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->watermark();

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
                $errors++;
            }
```